# How do I solve "AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'"?

Tags: python, pygame

My problem appeared when I tried to make my character walk by changing one variable and thus starting an animation.The problem however is that i get an AttributeError where "'Event' object has no attribute 'key'". I find it very strange as I have written this exact code before put this problem has never appeared in previous uses. I have tried rewriting the code many times, putting it outside of the event check and inside but nothing have worked.

```
while turnoff == False:
    
    screen.fill(white)
    
# event checks
    
for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            turnoff = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

#supposed to identify which key but can't make it work            
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                action -= 1
                frame = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action -= 3
                frame = 0
```

The error I get is
if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has no `key` attribute. However, the `KEDOWN` event has a `key` attribute:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        turnoff = True
        
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            action -= 1
            frame = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            action -= 3
            frame = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are asking for the `event.key` when the event is a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. You only want to check for a keypress when there is a `pygame.KEYDOWN`. Your code should look like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            turnoff = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:           
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                action -= 1
                frame = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action -= 3
                frame = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `key` attribute for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`:

> Read-only. The event type specific attributes of an event. The dict attribute is a synonym for backward compatibility.
>
> For example, the attributes of a KEYDOWN event would be unicode, key, and mod
> ([source](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.EventType.__dict__))

However, according to the [`event.c`'s source](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/936e866e17d5c09559ec821694134acfe45850cd/src_c/event.c#L651) there might be a `button` member. That is, if you want to check the mouse button. Otherwise check for `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN`.